# How to include regex and other standard libraries in esp8266 Arduino

Tags: compilation, libraries, arduino-esp8266

How should I include the regex library in my code? I've notice an old fork of this [esp8266 Arduino](https://github.com/toddtreece/esp8266-Arduino/tree/master/tools/macosx/xtensa-lx106-elf/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c%2B%2B/4.8.2/bits) repository have the regex.h that I think could use but it has string and wstring dependencies so should I add the whole "/bits" directory?

There's a "regex.h" library in the main [esp8266 Arduino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include) repository but I think it's a light version just to compile the necessary code and I should add the whole version in the project by my self.

Answer (score 2):

The regex header included as part of the repository is just part of GCC's C++ standard headers. Complete support for C++11's regex was not released until 4.9 (The Xtensa SDK only includes 4.8), so, you wont be able to really use that particular regex implementation.

You will need to find an alternate regex library, namely one that isn't dependent on any OS.